# Filtrar resultados Serializer Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, djangorestframework

Buenas, tengo un problema porque quiero filtar los datos de una FK en un serializer.

```
class ProductoArmarioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    imagenes = FotoSerializer(many=True)
    tallas = StockSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Producto
        fields = ['id', 'nombre', 'color', 'estado_prod', 'descrip', 'medidas', 'p_compra', 'categoria',
                     'p_venta', 'estado_rev', 'marca', 'imagenes','escaparate','tallas']


class MiArmarioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    productos = ProductoArmarioSerializer(many=True)
    usuario = UserSerializer()
    seguidores = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    likes = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Perfil
        fields = ['id','usuario','boutique','tel','entrg_pais','entrg_dep',
                    'entrg_ciudad','entrg_direccion','entrg_cp','rmt_pais','rmt_dep',
                    'rmt_direccion','rmt_ciudad','rmt_cp','num_cc','avatar','descp_armario',
                    'tipo_ident','cedula','nit','tarjeta','alt_tarjeta','propietario_cc',
                    'banco','tipo_cc','follow','seguidores','productos','likes']
```

quiero que los productos que devuelva sean los que tengan estado_rev=4 y el resto los descarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba a hacerlo desde views.py un ejemplo puede ser:

```
class PruebaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset=Producto.objects.filter(estado_rev=4)
    serializer_class = ProductoArmarioSerializer
```

Comment: el problema es que ProductoArmarioSerializer es un campo más de mi json, necesito filtrar los productos pero dentro de MiArmarioSerializer, no puedo separarlo

Comment: Si no te he entendido mal, creo que aplicando la misma idea podríamos hacer lo mismo con el modelo Perfil y el seriarilzer MiArmarioSerializer, solo que queryset=Perfil.objects.filter(Producto__estado_rev=4)